# Are the C functions recvfrom and sendto mutually exclusive?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, udp, thread-safety

I have one thread calling `recvfrom` with a timeout of 100 ms in a loop.
Another thread calls `sendto` periodically.

Does the `sendto` function wait until the `recvfrom` is released by the timeout (or a successful read) or does it send the data during that period of time.

Comment: What does your testing show?

Comment: Well, my program works as expected but I'm trying to determine if bugs will creep in as race conditions tighten.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Are the C functions recvfrom and sendto mutually exclusive?

No. They can both be executed by different threads at the same time.

`sendto()` doesn't wait for `recvfrom()` to read the data. It would place the data into the socket's buffer and return. Multiple `sendto()` may block for the previous `sendto()` to complete. If any error occurred (buffer full, message too  big etc) while sending then you can check inspect `errno` to check the cause of failure. Basically, you don't need to do any synchronization between `sendto()` and `recvfrom()` calls from the two threads; they are atomic operations.

Answer (score 1):

No, it does not wait, (at least, it does not wait any longer than necessary to gain thread-safe access to the comms stack).